# How to use costmap_2d to build grid map?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm a beginner. I'm trying to use costmap_2d package to build a grid map. Before this I used slam_gmapping to finish the job, by writing this node to launch file, but in didn't work for costmap_2d. I noticed that there are three nodes in costmap_2d package, so which one should I choose? How should I do to use it to build a map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245328/how-to-use-costmap_2d-to-build-grid-map?/) by [niubc](https://answers.ros.org/users/27846/niubc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 75 on 2016-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`costmap_2d` is not meant to do SLAM, this is drive around and actually create a map from sensor data. It is used to provide a means for path planning and obstacle avoidance, by providing an abstraction of the current environment as an occupancy grid map.

However, it is only filled with current sensor data (or other stuff) with respect to a fixed frame (e.g. the robot base frame or a world frame). It does not provide localization and thus cannot do mapping.

`slam_gmapping` or any other of the many SLAM packages out there is what you should use.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-10-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0